# How to add has_many attributes to a model in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

This is probably a ridiculously easy question, but I'm relatively new to cucumber.

I have a ruby-on-rails web application that I'm using cucumber to test.

In the feature file, I need to generating a model that several has_many attributes.

And I'm using the matrix method to create models like so...

```
And the following my_models exist:
| name     | date       | belongs_to_model                      | etc |
| my_model | 2014-02-09 | belongs_to_model: "belongs_to_model1" | ... |
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to populate the model with has_many attributes.  Obviously, it has to be done as some sort of array, but I can't figure out how.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails Cucumber is typically used for BDD. Your assertions will commonly be items on the webpage. Cucumber is not typically used to make unit level assertions. For unit level testing I'd recommend you take a look at [rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) and [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails).

Your stuck at "I can't figure out how to populate the model with has_many attributes" but that's because you're trying to solve the wrong problem (in my opinion).

Checkout the examples [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines). As you can see, they are very high level scenarios. Nothing is trying to describe the underlying architecture.

Comment: Thanks - I do appreciate the feedback.  It may well be that some of my terminology is wrong.  I looked at the examples - it seems like those are strictly a short-hand way to reduce repetition.  I guess if I can put my question in a more general way - in my .features file, I can put into a model a variable or another model - as long as the other model is strictly a one-to-one relationship. I would guess there is also a way to add an array of models that have a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: @TimMitchell You're still describing things that most usage of Cucumber is not intended for. Words like `model`, `variable`, `one-to-one relationship`, `array`, `one-to-many`. None of those descriptions should be in Gherkin. Those words/scenarios should be on unit tests. Your feature steps in Gherkin would be something like `Given a user` `When the user adds a blog post`, `Then a blog post is created`. Very top level, while underneath we should probably assume a user has-many blog posts. Focus on describing features, not architecture.

Comment: Okay - I think that maybe there's just a miscommunication - and it probably has at least a little to do with some of my naming conventions.  The 'belongs_to_model' reference in the table does NOT refer to any attempt to create or duplicate a 'belongs_to' reference in the Ruby model itself - that's already been done.  Neither does the reference to my_model have anything to do with what it in the Ruby model itself - it's just what I named it here in the features file.  All I want to do is automatically populate the data in the cucumber file.  I really think it's just that simple.

Comment: One thing that I think may help the miscommunication - the example table I've included does work.  And it would work if the name 'belongs_to_model' was actually named 'bonehead_model.'  As I said, it's just a naming convention - although the name I chose may have made it more confusing than less confusing.  All I want to do is do the reverse of what I've already done - and automatically populate a model that has many other models.  And I am pretty sure that's what a features file is for.

Comment: Not sure I completely follow but if you want to seed data, in your step definition use something like FactoryGirl to create a model based on whatever attributes you want. If you want to verify certain attributes on a model at the end of the feature you can use something like `expect(Model.last.date).to eql(some_date)` (but this is reaching into the database and is therefore testing a "side-effect" and not the feature, Sandi Metz might not approve :-).

Comment: Um... no.  I'm familiar with a seed file.  It populates your database for testing purposes.  The data is persistent, and you access it when you are actually running your app.  A feature file runs testing scenarios.  In order to do this, you typically have to populate your models - within the feature file - with data that only exists when you run the scenarios using cucumber.  In order to populate the models with this temporary data, often you use a matrix table - again, within the feature file.  All I've been asking is how you populate a one-to-many field.

Comment: Thanks for your help - but I don't really see a lot of forward progress here - even to the extent of our being on the same page.  For your effort, I'm going to give you the credit and search elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize - I think the answer to this was so simple that I just had some trouble seeing the forest through the trees.

Supposing you have a shepherd that has many sheep.  And you have a shepherd.features file intended to test this relationship through any number of scenarios.

In the features file, you could create a matrix table populating the following test shepherds:

```
Given the following shepherds exist:
      | shepherd  | name      |
      | shepherd1 | shep1name |
      | shepherd2 | shep2name |
      | shepherd3 | shep3name |
      | shepherd4 | shep4name |
```

In another matrix table, you could create a matrix table populating a list of test sheep.  However, you also want to specify that each sheep belongs to a specific shepherd.  And of course a shepherd can have more than one sheep (BTW - this was the crux of my question).
If you want shepherd1 to own sheep1 and sheep3, and shepherd2 to own sheep2 and sheep4, you would just do the following:

```
Given the following sheep exist:
      | sheep  | name       | shepherd  | 
      | sheep1 | sheep1name | shepherd1 |
      | sheep2 | sheep2name | shepherd2 |
      | sheep3 | sheep3name | shepherd1 |
      | sheep4 | sheep4name | shepherd4 |
```

Easy-Peasy!

Now, suppose that not only could one shepherd could have many sheep, but also a sheep could be owned by more than one shepherd.  In other words, you have a many-to-many relationship.  In this case, you would have a linker table called something like shepherd_sheep.  If you wanted to specify that sheep1 was owned by both shepherd1 and shepherd2; and that shepherd1 also owns sheep3 - you would just do something like this:

```
Given the following shepherd_sheep exist:
  | shepherd_sheep  | shepherd              | sheep           |
  | shepherd_sheep1 | shepherd: "shepherd1" | sheep: "sheep1" |
  | shepherd_sheep2 | shepherd: "shepherd3" | sheep: "sheep1" |
  | shepherd_sheep3 | shepherd: "shepherd1" | sheep: "sheep3" |
```

...and so on!